# How to register text on Write - python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text

How do I register what I write using the text in `tkinter` method that I can compare
example:

```py
if write == 'a':
    print ('a')
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, and provide a [mcve] that illustrates the problem you're trying to solve. That single sentence is very hard to understand.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but have you looked at any tkinter tutorials/tkinter code?

Comment: As Bryan mentioned, you need to specify what you want to do. There are many ways to achieve that. The context you need to provide decides which solution may fits to you.

Comment: The code you wrote is syntactically correct and will call `print` if `write` is set to the single character "a". What do you expect it to do other than that? The phrase "register" doesn't really mean anything in the context of tkinter.

Answer (score 1):

Since I understand You want to register what keys are being pressed at the moment when focus is on say `Entry()`. You can use this code:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Entry


def output(event):
    print(event.char, end='')


root = Tk()

user_input = Entry(root)
user_input.pack()

user_input.bind('<Key>', output)

root.mainloop()
```

the bind function will bind the widget to execute the given function whenever the bind event happens, bind also returns `event` to that given function so it is necessary that the function being called has an argument to get that event (even if You don't plan on using it) and in this case it is possible to access the character by using `event.char`. the `end=''` argument for print makes sure to print everything in one line as that is how it is typed in the entry box.

Also don't put `()` at the end of the function inside `.bind` so:

DO NOT

```
.bind('event', function())
```

as this will call that function immediately

DO

```
.bind('event', function)
```

which will call the function only when event is triggered

IF You need to pass arguments You can use `lambda` but that I won't go into since it is not as simple and should be understood before used

Comment: Usually you want to define normal python function instead of `lambda`s when OP doesn't seem to know that much about `tkinter`. It will make it easier for OP to understand what is going on in your code.